# "a" in "(a) short/long time"

Tags: nouns

Is there "a" in "(a) short/long time"? For example

> I must memorize many things in (a) short time.
>
> (A) long, long time ago, there was a king ....

Is "time" here a countable or uncountable noun?

Comment: I would say "I must memorize things in a short amount of time." and "A long, long time ago, there was a king..." I'll let someone else comment on how "time" functions grammatically in those sentences, though... :-)

Comment: They both need the article "a".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone else has provided an answer explaining why the article "a" should be included. You also asked about whether *time* was countable or uncountable; to answer that question, we can use the [much vs. many](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/541/03/) test:

> **Much** modifies only uncountable nouns:
>
> *How much money will we need?
>
> Much effort will be required to solve this problem.*
>
> **Many**
> modifies only countable nouns:
>
> *How many children do you have?
>
> Many Americans travel to Europe each year.*

Now, restructuring your sentences to fit the test:

> *I must memorize many things and I don't have much time*.

In that context, clearly *time* is an uncountable noun, as *much* fits, while *many* does not.

> *Many time ago, there was a king* ....

I would say that "much time ago" is not very good English, although it would still be better than "many time ago." I'd probably restructure the sentence as follows:

> *Many years ago, there was a king* ....

This shows that, at least in this context, *years* is a countable noun, but *time* is uncountable.

Comment: I think you should also try to answer the question the OP asked, which is whether the article *a* is appropriate in "(a) short/long time".  (Your own example sentences are quite different.)

Comment: @snailboat - The earlier answer given by JayHook addresses the _time_ vs. _a time_ issue. The O.P. also asked, "Is _time_ here a countable or uncountable noun?" which had been left unanswered. I'll make an edit, though, because I can see where some would think my answer doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted a portion of the entry in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.
It says that 'a time' means a period of time.

[image]

Comment: -1 This doesn't give any explanation as to why we say *His injuries will take **a** long time to heal*, but there's no article if we just say *His injuries will **take time** to heal*. Which as I understand it is what OP is asking about.

Comment: @FunbleFinger, OP specifically asked about **a long time**, **a short time**, which is clearly and succinctly explained in the dictionary. If you are in doubt, please read OP's question again.

Comment: @Fumble - That's an interesting angle; you could leave a third answer which discusses and explains that.

Comment: @J.R.: Offhand, I can't explain why we sometimes include the article with *time*, but not always. It's the same with *space* though. *"Life in the city is too crowded. I live in a village because I like to have space to relax"*.